# How to sort by JSON element

Tags: javascript, json, angular

[image: I have the following structure]

Each array has the following data:

```
{{ id: 39, treaty_number: "qwe", insurant_name: "222", belonging_to_the_holding_company: "test", date_start: "2016-04-15", etc }}
```

How do I sort each array in ascending order date_start?  
I am writing on Angular 4 and typescript v.2.4.1. It is possible and on pure JS. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just a standard javascript sort?
      .sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.date_start < b.date_start) { return -1; }
        if (a.date_start > b.date_start) { return 1; }
        return 0;
      });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates, you could sort it with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```
data.forEach(function (array) {
    array.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.date_start.localeCompare(b.date_start);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
jsonData.forEach(eachArray => {
   eachArray.sort( (aob, bob) => {
         if( aob.date_start < bob.date_start ) {
           return 1;
         } else if(aob.date_start > bob.date_start ) {
             return -1;
         }
         return 0;
   });
});
```